# Firefox not firing onload for dynamic nested iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have the following code that works on Chrome and MS Edge but not on Firefox.

Parent.html has this script.

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
var ifr1 = document.createElement('iframe');

ifr1.onload = function() {
    alert("iframe 1 loaded") //fires on all browsers
    script = ifr1.contentWindow.document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'PATH/TO/script.js';
    script.onload = function() {
        alert("script 1 onload") //fires on all browsers
    };
    ifr1.contentWindow.document.body.appendChild(script);
};
document.body.appendChild(ifr1);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It creates an iframe and loads script.js within that iframe.

Here is script.js which does the same thing like above -

```
var ifr2 = document.createElement('iframe');

ifr2.onload = function() {
    alert("iframe 2 loaded") //doesn't fire on Firefox
    script = ifr2.contentWindow.document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js';
    script.onload = function() {
        alert("script 2 onload")
    };
    ifr2.contentWindow.document.body.appendChild(script);
};
document.body.appendChild(ifr2);
```

It creates another iframe `ifr2` within the iframe `ifr1` created by Parent.html.

Now, Chrome and Edge show all the alerts properly but Firefox doesn't fire the onload event for `ifr2` loaded within `ifr1` (even IE fires the onload for `ifr2`). Any idea why?

Comment: Any messages on the devtools console?

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to create a simple html page - even just `<html><head></head><body></body></html>` (maybe even less) .. lets call it `empty.html`

if you now change Parent.html to

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
var ifr1 = document.createElement('iframe');

ifr1.onload = function() {
    alert("iframe 1 loaded") //fires on all browsers
    script = ifr1.contentWindow.document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'PATH/TO/script.js';
    script.onload = function() {
        alert("script 1 onload") //fires on all browsers
    };
    ifr1.contentWindow.document.body.appendChild(script);
};
ifr1.src = 'empty.html'; // add this code *******
document.body.appendChild(ifr1);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then it works as expected

Not sure why firefox does what it does - it could be because without the `src` attribute, the `iframe`'s location is `about:blank` - but why the first one works and not the second is a mystery to me

edit: well, **it did once then stopped again!!**

OK, really strange - if you add `ifr1.src = 'empty.html'` it works ... if you duplicate that in `script.js` it breaks again

Not sure I've answered you well, but at least I've given you a working kludge :p

Answer (score 0):

IMO this is a bug in Firefox because Firefox doesn't execute the `load` event inside iframes the way you would expect.  The developers over at Mozilla may disagree.  It all comes down to your definition of what "load" should mean, and it's more complicated than you think.

In any case the real issue is when to know it's safe to access `ifr2.contentWindow`, and the whole point of using `ifr2.onload` the way you did is so that you can figure out when `ifr2.contentWindow` exists.

Note, however, that the contentWindow and document are created immediately when `document.body.appendChild(ifr2)` executes, so if you move the `appendChild()` call to above your current code and remove the `onload` function, it will work as expected.

Alternatively you can change the `onload` function to something else and execute it directly after `appendChild()`, as such:

```
var ifr2 = document.createElement('iframe');
function loadit() {
    console.log("iframe 2 loaded")
    script = ifr2.contentWindow.document.createElement('script');
    script.src = '...';
    script.onload = function() {
        console.log("script 2 onload")
    };
    ifr2.contentWindow.document.body.appendChild(script);
};

// add the iframe to the document
document.body.appendChild(ifr2);

// now execute your script stuff:
loadit()
```

This should work across all (modern) browsers.

Answer (score 0):

While this is a bad practice and deprecated in chrome (it will show a warning in console.
adding this line before apending script tag fix the issue for me:

`iframe.contentWindow.document.write('<html><head></head><body></body></html>');`

It appears firefox needs it to init iframe and run javascript...